# how to play a video using video view and intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-videoview

I want to play a video on my DetaiActivity which is coming through Intent from another page I have an Image and video image is showing properly but I dont know how to play video

this is my myAdapter:

```
foodViewHolder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("Image",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemImage());
     intent.putExtra("Video",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemVideo());
     intent.putExtra("Name",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemName());
     intent.putExtra("Ingrediants",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemIngrediants());//
     intent.putExtra("Procedure",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemProcedure());
     mContext.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

});

and this my DetailActivity where i want to show video
I have tried something but it is not working

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    foodName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    foodImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);
    foodVideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.ivVideo2);
    foodIngrediants = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Ingrediants);//
    foodProcedure = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Procedure);


    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mBundle!=null){

        foodName.setText(mBundle.getString("Name"));
        foodIngrediants.setText(mBundle.getString("Ingrediants"));//
        foodProcedure.setText(mBundle.getString("Procedure"));
        foodImage.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));





            String videoURL = mBundle.getString("Video");
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(DetailActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(foodVideo);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(videoURL);
            foodVideo.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            foodVideo.setVideoURI(video);
            foodVideo.start();

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(mBundle.getString("Image"))
        .into(foodImage);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using MediaPlayer. Something like:

```
Player = MediaPlayer.create(activity, uri);
        Player.seekTo(0);
        Player.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);
        Player.start();
```

Comment: and ofc we need declare and initialization of Player as a MediaPlayer

Comment: I simply want to add videoview and play video